# In Setup project, difference between adding 'project output' and 'assembly'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am not sure what is the correct thing to add. In the Setup Project, when one clicks on "View" -> Editor" -> "File System", and then right-clicks and a pop-up appears.

If Project A uses Project B, must I add B.dll (assembly), or the output of Project B?

(Assuming that I have both Project A and Project B in the solution and that Project A has a reference to Project B.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Project Output will add what the project outputs, which may be one file or more, of any type. Since you have a project, add its output rather than just a DLL file. This will help if the name ever changes or there are other changes

But if the DLL was a binary from somewhere, then just add it as a DLL.

Comment: I've added the project output of a certain project, and therein is a xml file with log4net configurations. I've set the xml file's "Build" Property to Content, and its "Copy to Output Directory" as Copy Always, but the file doesn't get copied to the destination folder after the installation. Must I rather add it as a file in the installation settings (File System tab of the Setup project)?

Answer (score 0):

What is the output type of project `B` ? if `B`'s output type is an assembly then `adding B as project output` or `adding B as assembly` would be same.

Simply add `B` as assembly, that should be fine.

Comment: Okay, that answers it for B.dll. If B's output type was an executable, then what?

Comment: it depends on what you do with `B`s output, If you want to call any method within B then adding it as assembly should be fine, if the project type of B is windows application and you want to execute B then adding it as porject output should be fine. as i said, it depends on what you want to do with B